# CorrelationId error when approving pending approvals in API management

Tags: spfx, azure-ad

I have created an Azure AD secured API with azure function, and trying to call it from SPFx solution. I have uploaded the solution to app catalog, but when I go to API management under SharePoint Admin centre, when clicking on approve then getting the error as in image below.

[image]

Comment: Before deploying it to app catalog, did you tested it? Is your graph api working? Did you check that from postman?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. My app works with User.Read queries like `/me` because they are approved. but Group.Read queries don't work because they are not approved.